# Dart - How to refactor this loop with copywith?

Tags: flutter, dart

Need some help.

Let's say I have this List.

```
List<Program>
#1: complete = true, currentUuid = null
#2: complete = false, currentUuid = null
#3: complete = false, currentUuid = null
#4: complete = false, currentUuid = null
```

My Program class is @immutable and using the freezed package (no setter).

I need to loop through. When I detect the 1st complete = false, I need to assign a value to currentUuid. Only for #2 for my example.

```
#1: complete = true, currentUuid = null
#2: complete = false, currentUuid = '1231232131'
#3: complete = false, currentUuid = null
#4: complete = false, currentUuid = null
```

My current code which works but bloated.

```
List<Program> newPrograms = [];
    
int exitIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < programs.length; i++) {
  if (programs[i].complete) {
    newPrograms.add(programs[i]);
    continue;
  }

  Program newProgram = programs[i].copyWith(currentUuid: programs[i].uuid);
  newPrograms.add(newProgram);
  exitIndex = i;
  break;
}

for (int j = exitIndex + 1; j < programs.length; j++) {
  newPrograms.add(programs[j]);
}
```

Any ways to refactor this and make better dart/flutter codes? Thanks.

Comment: Do you explicitly not want to mutate the original `programs` list?  If mutating it acceptable, then you could just have a single loop that, when it finds the item you want, calls `.copyWith` and then `break`s.

Comment: @jamesdlin can you provide some code snippets?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < programs.length; i++) { if (!programs[i].complete) { programs[i] = programs[i].copyWith(...); break; } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `indexWhere` to get the index of the first item in the list that matches your condition and then selectively modify it (or to not change anything if no item matching the condition is found).

```dart
// Mutating
final currentIndex = programs.indexWhere((program) => !program.complete);
if (currentIndex >= 0) {
  final temp = programs[currentIndex];
  programs[currentIndex] = temp.copyWith(currentUuid: temp.uuid);
}

// Non-mutating
final newPrograms = List.of(programs);
final currentIndex = newPrograms.indexWhere((program) => !program.complete);
if (currentIndex >= 0) {
  final temp = newPrograms[currentIndex];
  newPrograms[currentIndex] = temp.copyWith(currentUuid: temp.uuid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Learned something new :)